# surjection between sets which are defined through a functor

Tags: category-theory

I'm facing the following problem and have no idea how to deal with it.

We consider a functor $T:\underline{Set}\rightarrow\underline{Set}$ and two sets $X,Y$. We can build the product $X\times Y$ and calculate $T(X\times Y)$. On the other hand we can built $T(X)\times T(Y)$.

If for example $T$ is the powerset functor, then $T(X\times Y)$ is larger than $T(X)\times T(Y)$ and there is a surjection $t:T(X\times Y)\twoheadrightarrow T(X)\times T(Y)$.

If $T$ is an arbitrary set functor, is there some sort of general abstract criterion or a categorical property of $T$, assuring the existence of such a surjection $t$?

Comment: It's more natural to ask when $t$ is an isomorphism. This is another way of saying that $T$ preserves finite products, and is guaranteed for example whenever $T$ is a right adjoint (but much weaker conditions are possible). It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: The assumption to be right adjoint and to preserve products seems to be to strong for what I actually want. I only need the existence of some right inverse $t^{-1}$, i.e. $t\circ t^{-1}=id$.

Comment: Actually $t:=<{T(\pi_X)},{T(\pi_Y)}>$ is the tupeling or a mediating morphism for the product $T(X)\times T(Y)$ and I want to know when it is surjective. It doesn't have to be an isomorphism, i.e. bijective.

Comment: It's surjective when it's surjective. I'm not aware of an especially nice criterion. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What I want is... The arrow $t:T(X\times Y)\twoheadrightarrow T(X)\times T(Y)$ always exists. I want to reverse it. I want to "access" $T(X\times Y)$ from $T(X)\times T(Y)$.

Comment: But why? What kind of $T$ are you looking at?

Comment: $T$ is just any $\underline{Set}$ endofunctor. No special requirements so far. There is no short story for where this problem comes from. I will think about how to explain it in more detail. But it works for the powerset functor ($t$ is surjective), so I was wondering about other functors. A counterexample would also be interesting.

Comment: For example, the functor $T(X) = X \times S$ for a fixed set $S$ does not have this property as long as $S$ has at least two elements.

Comment: Thx for the counterexample. Now I think I don't have to solve the question whether $t$ is surjective or not. Because I can "access"  $T(X\times Y)$  via $T(\pi_X)^{-1}\circ\pi_{T(X)}:T(X)\times T(Y)\rightarrow T(X\times Y)$. Thats all I need :-)

Comment: What? But you have no guarantee that $T(\pi_X)$ is invertible.

Comment: $\pi_X$ has a right-inverse and  $T(\pi_X)$ too. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Not if $Y$ is empty.